# How to name properties of compex @RequestParams in @RestController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

Is it possible to rename the parameters used inside a GET webservice in spring? Like `search.limitResults` in the following example:

`localhost:8080/firstname=test&search.limitResults=10`

You get the idea. Can this be achieved?

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   private String test(RestParams p) {

   }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RestParams {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    //is that possible to nest?
    @XmlElement(name = "search")
    private MyComplexSearch search;
    public MyComplexSearch getSearch() {return search;}
    public void setSearch(MyComplexSearch) {this.search = search;}

    @XmlRootElement(name = "search")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class MyComplexSearch {
       private int limitResults;
       //some more
    }
}
```

The request will not work with the code above. Instead one would have to use `myComplexSearch` as the objects name.

`localhost:8080/firstname=test&myComplexSearch.limitResults=10`

How can I redefine the name of the input property, without having to rename the java class itself?

Comment: If you have a `get/setSearch` it will just work.

Comment: I indeed have them named this way (see edit above), but still same issue.

Comment: If the method is indeed as you have shown, it should just work. If it doesn't you aren't using the method as presented here or have some misconfiguration...

Answer (score 0):

Nested classes have to be **static**.

`public static class MyComplexSearch`